# Get div coordinates in drag and drop

Tags: angular

In this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7tnux) I have a div with a `mwlDraggable` directive (see [angular-draggable-droppable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-draggable-droppable) library).

The drag moves fine, but I need to know the top/left coordinates of the div when I drop it in another div. The drop event gives me the x/y coordinates of the mouse pointer, but not of the div. Any ideas how to achieve this? I'm also open to use other dragging libraries.

```
<div 
    mwlDraggable 
    [ghostDragEnabled]="true"
    [ghostElementTemplate]="ghostTemplate">
    Drag me!
</div>


<ng-template #ghostTemplate>
    <div style="width:50px;height:50px;border:2px dashed black"></div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: For what purposes? Because if it just needs to be a visual effect you can hide the mouse cursor and show a unicode symbol or some FA icon at the center which will be a placeholder for the mouse pointer

Comment: t's not for a visual effect. I will drop the div in a canvas and I need to know the exact top/left coordinates of the div that I'm dropping.

Comment: I don't have any code for you but from what i've tried, you need to listen to the `dragStart` event and change the position of the `ghostTemplate` to be `left:25px` and `top:25px`. I tried to edit your stackBlitz but could make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get coordinates of ghost element when it is being dropped I would listen to `dragEnd` event and make use of `@ViewChild` Angular decorator:

**template.html**

```
<div 
    mwlDraggable 
    [ghostDragEnabled]="true"
    [ghostElementTemplate]="ghostTemplate"
    (dragEnd)="dragEnd($event)"  <==================== add this
    >
    Drag me!
</div>

<ng-template #ghostTemplate>
    <div #ghostEl ...></div>
         ^^^^^^^^
         and this
</ng-template>
```

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('ghostEl') ghostEl: ElementRef<any>;

dragEnd(event) {
  const droppedElement = this.ghostEl.nativeElement.parentNode;
  const { top, left } = droppedElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(top, left);
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s15rsg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**